# Rendering a file/template with layout outside of controller with Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Currently I am rendering a view in Rails 4 outside of a Controller with this code:

```
av = ActionView::Base.new(ActionController::Base.view_paths, {}, ActionController::Base.new)
av.config = Rails.application.config.action_controller
av.class_eval do
  include ApplicationHelper
end

html = av.render(
  file: '/users/index',
  locals: {}
)
```

How can I render the view inside of a layout?
The following does not work:

```
html = av.render(
  file: '/users/index',
  locals: {}
  layout: 'layouts/application' 
)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I solved it. It works fine as expected:

```
html = av.render(
  file: '/users/index',
  locals: {}
  layout: 'layouts/application' 
)
```

What does not work is:

```
html = av.render(
  file: '/users/index.pdf',
  locals: {}
  layout: 'layouts/application' 
)
```

looks like it searches for a layout `layouts/application.pdf.erb` or similar. It does fail silently though.